# Small panGesture is taking as singleTap gesture, why? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have implemented all the gestures in my app, and returned in `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` as YES.
I am facing problem is when I pan a little, it consider it as a `singleTap` and the code for `singleTap` is executing. I can understand, I have to do conditional code in `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`, but the two gesture which I am getting is `rotationGesture` and `panGesture`?
I am stuck.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post code snippet here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself,

For others who are facing such difficulty,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[singleTapGesture class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[panGesture class]]) {
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For taping, zooming there are multiple third party view available, you use them as they are already tested. I prefer ZDStickerView for most of my apps [link](https://github.com/zedoul/ZDStickerView).